# Myriades, milliasses, gazillions & très grands nombres

Tags: vocabulaire, nombres, néologismes

Depuis quelques années, le terme **« gazillion »** est entré dans mon vocabulaire français. J’ai longtemps fréquenté ce terme en anglais, mais je ne croyais pas être la personne responsable de son utilisation dans le français quotidien. Je croyais plutôt avoir attendu et guetté, tel un prédateur à l’affût, son arrivée dans la langue de Molière avant de l’incorporer à mon discours.

Aujourd’hui, cependant, je me rends compte de ma possible erreur de jugement, car ce mot semble demeurer très rare en français : *Robert* et *Larousse* ne l’inlcuent pas, le *Bon usage* n’en parle pas, le *Trésor de la langue française* l’ignore. En outre, j’ai aussi découvert qu’un terme équivalent *(un nombre énorme et indéterminé)* existe *(ou existait)* en français : **« [milliasse](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/milliasse) »**, présenté dans le *Bon usage* avec cette délicieuse citation de Japrisot :

> Un de ces grands machins blancs *[= un yacht]* avec des moteurs de je ne sais combien de **milliasses** de canassons.

Ce terme ne fait plus partie des dictionnaires les plus courants depuis déjà plusieurs décennies, et est déclaré vieilli par le *Dictionnaire culturel* de Robert et par le *Trésor*, familier et souvent péjoratif de surcroît par ce dernier. Il désignait aussi mille millions à une certaine époque, mais *milliards* l’a supplanté à cet usage.

Il me semble, je sens ce jugement assez objectif mais corrigez-moi si je fais erreur, qu’un terme commençant par *mill-* ne saurait désormais être assez fort pour signifier l’innombrable.

Il y a bien aussi **« [myriade](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/myriade) »**, jadis *dix mille*, maintenant un très grand nombre.

Et finalement, mais ce n’est pas ce qui m’intéresse ici, les hyperboliques **« [infini](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/infini) »** et **« [infinité](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/infinit%C3%A9) »**, qui ont une signification en mathématiques, mais outrepassent la réalité palpable de notre univers.

---

- *« Myriades »* et *« milliasses »* sont-ils appropriés dans le discours contemporain pour les très très grands nombres *(le nombre de parties d’échec possibles, ou, plus modestement, le nombre d’octets publiés dans l’histoire de* YouTube) ?
- Quelle place occupe *« gazillion »* dans ce panorama ? L’utiliserait-on, le cas échéant, au singulier *(comme souvent en anglais)* ou au pluriel *(comme milliasses et myriades)* ?
- D’autres termes concurrents, que j’aurais oubliés ou que je ne connaîtrais pas ?

Comment: Je m'autorise à répondre, en commentaire, à ces questions en tant que français natif ayant suivi un parcours scolaire normal à l'école publique et ayant une culture correcte. Voici donc un avis d'un français moyen : je n'ai personnellement jamais rencontré les termes "milliasses" et "gazillion". Quant au mot "myriade", je l'ai uniquement rencontré dans les livres, particulièrement dans les contes et les récits. Il me paraît employé lorsqu'il s'agit d'une quantité exceptionnelle, presque incroyable.

Comment: Je pense que myriade signifie un grand nombre indéfini sans pour autant que ce soit exceptionnel ou incroyable (ou presque). Je me rappelle de l'usage des documentaire animaliers du terme myriade pour décrire le nombre d'animaux dépendants d'une quelconque ressource. e.g : *Cette source d'eau est vitale pour une myriade d'animaux.*

Comment: @randomhopeful Un peu comme un synonyme de *large éventail* (en un seul mot), dans votre exemple, si je comprends bien. Ou était-ce plutôt un compte des animaux individuels, plutôt que des espèces?

Comment: @randomhopeful Par ailleurs, il existe des exemples où l’ampleur de la myriade est vraiment exceptionnelle. La citation du TLFi: *«La clarté de son visage est faite de **myriades** d'expressions, comme une nappe d'eau est faite de **myriades** de molécules et cette transparence enfantine (...) est riche de tous les reflets créés depuis l'origine du monde...»* Si les myriades d’expressions sont sans doute comparativement en petite quantité, les myriades de molécules d’une nappe d’eau dépassent tout simplement notre entendement.

Comment: @Feelew Le contexte laissait imaginer que le narrateur parlait des innombrables animaux d'espèces différentes vivant près de la source. Quant au mot myriade, je voulais dire qu'il avait une connotation factuelle plutôt que grandiose. Qu'on l'utilise pour décrire une quantité indéfinie sans pour autant qu'elle dépasse l'entendement ou les limites du raisonnable. Tout comme dans votre exemple, la comparaison est théâtrale mais l'usage de myriade invoquait le caractère indéfini du nombre des expressions et des molécules.

Comment: @randomhopeful Peut-être dans son acception première de dix mille???

Comment: @Feelew Vous avez été plus réactif que ma modification ( :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Le suffixe *[-ade](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/myriade/2)* est d'origine savante et la *myriade* est à tout le moins [étymologiquement](http://cnrtl.fr/etymologie/myriade) adaptée depuis l'Antiquité à cette tâche (relié à l'adjectif grec pour « innombrable » nous dit-on)... Je la trouve personnellement utile (et douce à l'oreille) mais je la connais surtout au singulier (*une myriade (de)*, plus exactement). Quant au suffixe [*-asse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-asse), le *TLFi* y classe la *milliasse* en emploi *péjoratif* avec les substantifs inanimés, comme on l'identifie en question, avec la mention *par plaisanterie* ; c'est donc un peu différent de l'effet recherché et moins utile à mon avis...
- Probablement aucun à mon avis mais la réflexion sur le *gazillion* en vaut la chandelle... Tout d'abord, je ne suis pas certain de sa prononciation (soit comme *million* soit comme *papillon*, sans doute le premier...), sans doute parce que je ne connais pas l'usage du [*zillion*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=zillion) (1942) et du [*gazillion*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=gazillion) quelques 40 ans plus tard, le tout avec préfixe arbitraire ou inventé (*Etymonline*). Par ailleurs la morphologie du terme de langue anglaise appelle une réflexion sur les [préfixes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Pr%C3%A9fixes_en_fran%C3%A7ais) en français... peut-être des noms composés de préfixes plus exotiques que les grecs et latins, ou en combinaison avec plusieurs préfixes, mais je ne saurais dire comment exactement...
- Ce qui me vient d'abord à l'esprit a été développé dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/28977) avec les unités de poids et je n'ai rien trouvé d'aussi polyvalent (avec les inanimés, la somme d'argent etc.). Ensuite j'ai pensé au syntagme *un nombre [incalculable](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incalculable)*, l'aspect incalculable étant plus concret que l'*infinité*. Aussi l'adjectif [*interminable*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/interminable), mais c'est surtout par exagération, ou littéraire pour une caractéristique de l'individu. J'ai enfin retrouvé le préfixe [*archi-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/archi-), sans doute en lien avec *archi-millionnaire* etc., la *haute intensité*, mais on indique que la formation touche surtout le *défaut d'esprit* accentuant l'aspect familier et péjoratif des compositions (TLFi) ; un préfixe n'est pas un substantif, mais il peut servir à en former, ainsi que des adjectifs...

Comment: Surtout des impressions plutôt qu'une réponse particulièrement pointue, mais bon, on essaye ! Merci !

Comment: J’utilise gazillion rimant avec million en effet. C'est ainsi que l'original anglais est construit, et le choix semble logique en français. Mais comme vous (et les autres) le dites, ce n'est pas *(encore)* français.

Comment: J'aime bien votre proposition avec le préfixe archi-. Est-ce qu’archillion pourrait un jour émerger????? se demande fébrilement Feelew...

Comment: L'archi... beurrée de balles ! ahhaha. Je ne sais pas si l'allusion au nombre est toujours si utile. J'ai essayé de réfléchir aux contextes, et je ne sais pas si j'ai besoin d'un truc qui unifierait le tout comme le _zillion_. Ensuite j'ai pensé au truc _supercalifragilisticexpidélilicieux_, mais c'est une translittération de l'anglais ça... Merci !

Answer (score 5):

Je ne connaissais pas *milliasses* avant de venir ici. Je connais *gazillion* mais uniquement via mon exposition à la langue anglaise sur internet, pas par la conversation courante en français.

*Myriades* s'entend un peu moins rarement. Je l'associe surtout à Hubert Reeves qui l'utilise souvent et qui a dans sa bouche une sonorité toute poétique avec le roulement du R.

Dans le langage courant autour de moi, on utilise surtout *des tonnes* ou bien *des caisses*, ce qui représente un vraiment très grand nombre quand on parle d'objets sans masse ou sans volume comme la quantité d'octets diffusés par YouTube depuis le commencement.

Comment: Ma fille m’a fait remarquer *paquet* (ou *méchant paquet*, à la québécoise), un peu dans la veine de vos tonnes et caisses. Merci pour votre réponse, et un pouce en haut pour le petit à-côté sur Hubert Reeves, dont la voix est en effet bien agréable.

Comment: On entend parfois aussi un kyrielle, ou encore sur un mode plus humoristique une "foultitude", mélange de foule et de multitude.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai jamais entendu utiliser "milliasse", cela fait fort péjoratif. Pourquoi pas "mégachiée", tant qu'à faire? (une mégachiée = 11 millions)

En termes concurrents, on aurait:

- "Cent mille milliards", faisant allusion aux *Cent mille milliards de poèmes* de Queneau, à réserver aux cercles littéraires.
- "Mille milliards de mille", "Mille milliards de mille millions de mille", et autres expressions dérivées utilisant l'apostrophe classique du capitaine Haddock, que l'on devrait pouvoir utiliser partout.
- "Plus de 8000 unités", à réserver aux Otakus, amateurs de gifs animés et autres rescapés du club Dorothée.

Comment: Je note l’amusante *mégachiée*, composée du préfixe méga-, qui multiplie par un million, et de chiée, de valeur onze (comme dans *onze fait chiée*). Merci de la découverte. Je ne l’avais jamais rencontrée. Avec un peu de reformulation (détail et ton, principalement), vous avez mon vote. Merci.

Comment: Je pense qu'il s'agit de "Plus de 9000 unités", si tu fais allusion à l'expression "Over 9000" issue de DBZ.

Comment: Ou aussi son homologue *tétrachiée* :)