# Comment exprimer « zillions » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques, anglicismes

D'après [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers#-illion):

> Words with the suffix -illion (e.g., zillion,[20] gazillion,[21]
> jillion[22]) are often used as informal names for unspecified large
> numbers by analogy to names of large numbers such as million (106),
> billion (109) and trillion (1012).
>
> These words are intended to denote a number that is large enough to be
> unfathomable and are typically used as hyperbole or for comic effect.
> They have no precise value or order. They form ordinals and fractions
> with the usual suffix -th, e.g., "I asked her for the jillionth
> time.", or "-illionaire" to describe wealthy people.

Par exemple:

> In the case of an ideal gas, we do not care to know the velocities and locations of the zillions of individual molecules.
>
> Dans le cas d'un gaz idéal, nous ne nous soucions pas de connaître les
> vitesses et les emplacements des zillions de molécules individuelles.

Peut-on employer en français **zillions** ? Faut-il employer **des millions de** ou bien **des tas de** ? Y a-t-il en français un mot (ou une expression) aussi hyperbolique et/ou comique que le mot anglais ?

Comment: Un peu de lecture : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28974/myriades-milliasses-gazillions-tr%c3%a8s-grands-nombres

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : J'arrive toujours un peu tard :-)! Duplicata ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Myriades, milliasses, gazillions & très grands nombres](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28974/myriades-milliasses-gazillions-tr%c3%a8s-grands-nombres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour retranscrire l'effet comique une option est de donner une précision absurde, par exemple:

> Dans le cas d'un gaz idéal, nous ne nous soucions pas de connaître les vitesses et les emplacements des *trois cent quarante millions six cent quatre-vingt-douze mille milliards*  de molécules individuelles.

Cela permet d’insister à la fois sur le grand nombre et sur le fait que la valeur numérique exacte n'est pas pertinente.

Comment: Dans ce registre, moi je préfère la *tétrachiée* ;-)

Comment: Je pense que juste _mille milliards_ suffit ! Selon moi la précision absurde est de trop. La référence implicite au capitaine Haddock amène la dimension burlesque

Comment: Je crois aussi que *mille milliards* suffit, mais j'aime bien parfois une précision absurde. Mais il faut savoir jusqu'où on peut passer les bornes. Je crois que *trois cent quarante-deux milliards*, sans précision supplémentaire, insiste déjà assez sur une une précision absurde. Étirer la sauce jusqu'aux unités (on pourrait aussi faire pire en spécifiant dix-huit décimales), c'est risquer de lasser son auditoire en lui laissant croire qu'on s'écoute parler.

Answer (score 1):

L'Oxford Dictionary (ou Oxford Hachette French Dictionary) et d'autres dictionnaires traduisent le mot "zillion" par *des million et des millions (de)* ou par *des tas et des tas (de)*.

Le mot *zillion* est employé en français pour signifier une très grande quantité, pas précisément déterminée, surtout dans des traductions de livres originellement écrits en anglais. Le mot est cité [dans le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/zillion) comme anglicisme:

> Pour une étude supplémentaire et une référence des neuf zillions
>   quatre compétences de Vim, reportez-vous à l'excellent manuel
>   utilisateur et manuel de référence de Bram Moolenaar, l'auteur de Vim.
>   — (Carla Schroder, Linux en action, traduit par François Cerbelle,
>   Sébastien Namèche & Isabelle Urbain, éd. O'Reilly Media, 2005, p. 57)
>
> — Papa ! Pourquoi tu ne m'a pas rappelée ? Je t'ai laissé un zillion
>   de messages ! — Un zillion, je ne sais pas, mais bien trop en tout
>   cas. — (Rainbow Rowell, Fangirl, traduit par Cédric Degottex, éd.
>   Castelmore, 2014, chap. 6)

Quelques synonymes sont cités, mais leur usage est moins courant.